# manage list of items in individual Categorized menu in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In my angular app, I tried to make a categorized navigation menu list. There is a select box. When a menu is selected, menuItems(which is an array) listed into it, will be shown down the select box. Each time I add a new menu(say Header Menu or Footer Menu), I can add items(each objects will contain properties such as name, url) in menuItems array. Here is my menu array with menuItems array into it.

```
$scope.menus = [
    {
        name: menu_name1,
        menuItems: [
            {
                name: "home",
                url: "/"
            },
            {
                name: "about",
                url: "/about"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: category_name2,
        menuItems: [
            {
                name: "company",
                url: "/company"
            },
            {
                name: "infos",
                url: "/infos"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        ......
        ......
    }
];
```

when I select a menu, I take its index using $index, can select the specific category of that index and store it into a variable. and with that index I can select that I tried to select that menu category and tried to view it name only for checking purpose, but its not working.

```
<select name="menuCategory" id="menuCategory"
        ng-options="menu.name for menu in websiteContent.globalPage.menus track by $index"
        ng-change="getCurrentMenu($index)" ng-model="currentMenu" class="form-control">
</select>
```

and here is my function,

```
$scope.getCurrentMenu = function(index){
        $scope.currentMenu = $scope.websiteContent.globalPage.menus[index];
};
```

What I want to do is to select a certain menu category then I can add items in menuItems array and can edit those individual items. For any category, list of items in its array will be shown. How can I make it work? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set option value as object of selected menu

```
<select ng-model="currentMenu" ng-options="menu as menu.name for menu in menus"></select>
```

look example [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/sZvVsiufbbiXG43sAEec?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a ton. It really helped me a lot.Now I can use currentMenu.list to select the list of items in each individual menu category. But I have a question. How can I take currentMenu and assign it to a variable in our controller. Like
$scope.newVar = $scope.currentMenu;
I tried to do it in this way but didnot get any result;

Comment: you can use `$scope.currentMenu` itself

Comment: but if you want assing it to new variable you need use `$scope.$watch`

Comment: I faced a problem. When I am logging $scope.currentMenu, it says undefined. Also I cannot push any items into it. 
`$scope.currentMenu.menuItems.push({
    name: $scope.menuitem.name, 
    url: $scope.menuitem.url
})`
gives me error that `Cannot read property 'menuItems' of undefined`. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I faced a problem. When I am logging $scope.currentMenu, it says `undefined`. Also I cannot push any items into it. `$scope.currentMenu.menuItems.push({ name: $scope.menuitem.name, url: $scope.menuitem.url })` gives me error that `Cannot read property 'menuItems' of undefined`. Am I doing anything wrong?